# Sharepoint connection fails (Winforms, VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sharepoint

I did a small development where it is necessary to connect to a SharePoint list, the development works well with my user, but when testing with another user who has the same privileges on the site, it sends the following error message

> **"The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft Account System. "**

I already tried with other users that the site are owners, but I get the same result.
Can you help me see what is the error in the above?

This is my code.

```
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form4

    Dim siteUrl As String = "https://example.sharepoint.com/site/SiteExample/"
    Dim context As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
    Dim web As Web

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            Dim userNameSP As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim password As String = TextBox2.Text
            Dim secureString As SecureString = New NetworkCredential("", password).SecurePassword

            Dim cred = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(userNameSP, secureString)
            Dim clientContext As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
            clientContext.Credentials = cred
            Dim web As Web = clientContext.Web
            Dim oWebsite As Web = clientContext.Web
            Dim collList As ListCollection = oWebsite.Lists

            Dim oList As List = collList.GetByTitle("Example Test")

            clientContext.Load(oList)

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

            Dim query As CamlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()

            query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Category/></ViewFields></Query></View>"

            Dim AllItems As ListItemCollection = oList.GetItems(query)
            clientContext.Load(AllItems)
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

            If AllItems.Count > 0 Then

                ... Do Something

            end if

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the user account enable MFA Authentication ?

I tested the same code snippet with a normal user account without MFA, it's working as expected.

Please check MFA Status in this:

https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/UserManagement/MultifactorVerification.aspx?BrandContextID=O365

If enabling the MFA, please disable it, as CSOM didn't support MFA currently.

Comment: @Jerry_MST, thank you for your answer, in this case the MFA is enabled, this is because the accounts are corporate and can't disable the option, is yes or yes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use  OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager object to handle MFA, please check this demo:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-csom-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-with-multi-factor-authentication-enabled

Comment: Is there any update ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: its working, thank you so much for your help. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution code to do log-in in a sharepoint.

```
      Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
        Imports System.IO
        
        Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
        Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
        Imports System.Security
        Imports System.Net

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

                Dim siteUrl As String = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/TRAINING/"
                Dim authManager = New OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager()
                Dim ctx As ClientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl)
                Dim web As Web = ctx.Web
                ctx.Load(web, Function(w) w.Title)
                ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                Console.WriteLine("You have connected to {0} site, with Multi Factor Authentication enabled!!", web.Title)
    
            Try
                Do Something...
    
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred:" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
    
    End Sub
```

Sorry for the delay.

Regards.